# Umbraco v10 / dotnet vs Docker

Tags: .net, docker, .net-core, umbraco

I've been struggling with setting up umbraco 10 with Docker, so I was hoping you could push me in the right direction.

I have created a brand new Umbraco with the newest dotnet sdk installed on mac.

```
$ dotnet new umbraco --name Umbraco10Test
```

And then I can publish it by doing

```
$ dotnet publish Umbraco10Test.csproj --configuration Release --no-restore --output ./app
$ cd app
$ dotnet Umbraco10Test.dll
```

And then I can go to `http://localhost:5000` and install my Umbraco. So far so good. And if in my appsettings.json file add:

```
 "Kestrel": {
   "Endpoints": {
     "properties": {
       "Url": "http://localhost:4000"  
     }
   } 
 }
```

I am able to change to port listening to 4000 instead of 5000.

Cool. Now I want to put it into Docker. I have created this Dockerfile.

```
########################
### build
########################
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build

ARG PROJECT

WORKDIR /src

ENV PROJECT=${PROJECT}

COPY . .

RUN dotnet restore "${PROJECT}.csproj"

RUN dotnet publish "${PROJECT}.csproj" --configuration Release --no-restore --output /app

########################
### final
########################
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 

ARG PROJECT

WORKDIR /app

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS "http://*:4000"

ENV DLL="${PROJECT}.dll"

COPY --from=build /app .

RUN echo "#!/bin/sh\ndotnet ${DLL}" > ./entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x ./entrypoint.sh

EXPOSE 4000

ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

And then I build and run the docker with this:

```
$ docker build --no-cache --progress=plain -t umbraco10test_docker --build-arg PROJECT=Umbraco10Test .
$ docker run --rm -d -p 4000:4000 --name umbraco10 umbraco10test_docker
```

If i try and go to http://localhost:4000 then I get a `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` error page, and if I try to curl this I get a `curl: (52) Empty reply from server`

If I `docker exec -it umbraco10 /bin/bash` into the running container and try execute the same entrypoint.sh file created by the Dockerfile, I get this error:

```
Unhandled exception. System.IO.IOException: Failed to bind to address http://127.0.0.1:4000: address already in use.
 ---> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.AddressInUseException: Address already in use
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (98): Address already in use
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UpdateStatusAfterSocketErrorAndThrowException(SocketError error, String callerName)
```

So it seems to be runnning. I have a suspicion that it has to do with https and ssl, and another port or maybe 0.0.0.0 vs 127.0.0.1, but can figure it out.  Hope you can help me :)

I have created a demo repo if anyone is interested :)
https://github.com/lalunastudio/umbraco-10-docker-demo

// Peter

Comment: The symptom and the very last error message suggest that you may in fact need to change that `"Url": "http://0.0.0.0:4000"`.

Comment: YES!! That was the problem. Thanks. 2 nights of trying every combination of dockerfiles, ports and settings  and I didn't saw this. Worked like a charm. If you create an answer, I will mark as solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, processes in Docker containers must listen on the special 0.0.0.0 "all interfaces" address.  If they listen on 127.0.0.1, that binds to a container-private localhost interface, and your process will be reachable from neither another container nor the containing host.

In your case this means you need to change the listener URL

```json
"Url": "http://0.0.0.0:4000"
```

Note that this will not be the address you use to contact the service.  From another container on the same Docker network, use its container name or Compose service name and port 4000; from outside Docker but on the same host, use `localhost` and the first published port number (`docker run -p` or Compose `ports:` option); from a different host use the host's DNS name and the first published port number.